# How to make Watson understand the context, identify an entity already mentioned during the conversation and respond about it?

Tags: entity, ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

I want to make Watson identify an Entity already mencioned by the user and respond about it. For example:

User asks:
- Do you have "product"?

Watson says:
- Yes, we have it.

User asks:
- How much is it?

Could Watson respond to the price of the product by identifying the entity mentioned in the user's first question?

Answer (score 0):

Your Watson Conversation will help with Understand what the user wants and the objects, and your application (with code) will verify these values and do something you need.

Based on your business roles, you can do this with code, is more simple because if your value from your product change, you always have to edit within Workspace Conversation.

You need to [access](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-entities) the value from your `entity` with code and make your application send message if the user ask about prices for your product.

**Like:**

```
if(intents.intent[0] === 'wantPrices' && entities.entity[0].value == 'sound'){
  // do something 
  data.output.text[0] = "The price of your sound is " + JSON.stringify(sqlSelectQueryValue);
}
```

See one more functional Official example from [IBM Developers](https://github.com/doconnor78/conversation-simple-weather/blob/master/app.js#L239).